# linux shell script that allows you to launch and stop an application

Tags: scripting

(Editors note: Google-translated text follows)

Hello to you. I would like to create a shell script that allows launching or stopping an application. The shell script will take a start or stop parameter to respectively start or stop an application. obviously the application in question must be indicated in our shell script.

thank you in advance .. I am open to all proposals

---

Original French:

bonjour a vous. Je souhaiterai créer un script shell qui permet lancer ou d'arrêter une application. Le script shell prendra en paramètre start ou stop pour respectivement lancer ou arrêter un application. bien évidemment l'application en question doit être indiquée dans notre script shell..

merci d'avance .. je suis ouvert à toutes propositions

Answer (score 1):

Given the bash-script-template below, you could either

- add long-options `--start`and `--stop` to set variables and use those in an if-statement.
- you could check if `start` or `stop` are in `${remaining_args[@]}` and then use that information:

```
if printf '%s\n' ${remaining_args[@]} | grep -Pq '^start$' ; then
  start your app
elif printf '%s\n' ${remaining_args[@]} | grep -Pq '^stop$' ; then
  stop your app
fi
```

**And here's the template:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash - 
#===============================================================================
#
#          FILE: <filename here>
#
#   DESCRIPTION: 
#
#       OPTIONS: ---
#  REQUIREMENTS: ---
#          BUGS: ---
#         NOTES: ---
#        AUTHOR: 
#  ORGANIZATION: 
#       CREATED: 
#       LICENSE: 
#      REVISION:  ---
#===============================================================================

#=== Init ======================================================================
set -o nounset   # exit on unset variables.
set -o errexit   # exit on any error.
set -o errtrace  # any trap on ERR is inherited
#set -o xtrace    # show expanded command before execution.

unalias -a       # avoid rm being aliased to rm -rf and similar issues
LANG=C           # avoid locale issues
VERBOSE=         # Don't be verbose, unless given '-v'-option

ScriptVersion="1.0"

trap "cleanup" EXIT SIGTERM SIGINT

#=== Functions =================================================================
usage () {
  echo "

  Usage :  ${0##/*/} [options] [--]

  Options:
  -h|--help     Display this message
  -V|--version  Display script version
  -v|--verbose  Print informational text

  "
  exit 0
} # ----------  end of function usage  ----------

option_handling () {
  # see /usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples/getopt-parse.bash
  OPTS=$(getopt --name "$0" \
    --options 'hVv' \
    --longoptions 'help,version,verbose' \
    --shell bash \
    -- "$@") \
    || (echo; echo "See above and try \"$0 --help\""; echo ; exit 1)

  eval set -- "$OPTS"
  unset OPTS

  while true ; do
    case "$1" in
      -h|--help)
        usage
        ;;
      -V|--version)
        echo "$0 -- Version $ScriptVersion"; exit 0
        ;;
      -v|--verbose)
        VERBOSE=true
        shift
        ;;
      --)
        shift ; break
        ;;
      *)
        echo 'This should not have happened.  Probably getopt is misconfigured.'
        exit 2
        ;;
    esac
  done
  remaining_args=( "$@" )
} # ----------  end of function option_handling  ----------

_verbose () { # printf '%s\n' if VERBOSE, be silent otherwise
  if [[ ${VERBOSE} ]]; then
    _verbose() {
      printf '%s\n' "$@"
    }
    _verbose "$@"
  else
    _verbose() {
      :
    }
  fi
} # ----------  end of function _verbose  ----------

cleanup () { # Will be called by the trap above, no need to call it manually.
  :
} # ----------  end of function cleanup  ----------

# here you could source your scripting-libraries
# and make use of flatten.sh later.
# see https://github.com/markgraf/flatten.sh.git

#=== Main ======================================================================
main () {
  option_handling "$@"

  # Your script goes here...

} # ----------  end of function main  ----------

main "$@"

#=== End =======================================================================
```